# Make VATS the Default in Fallout 3?

Tags: fallout-3

Is there a way to always use VATS in Fallout 3?  If I hit "V", it goes to the VATS system and then when the turn is over, it goes back to real time combat.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You mean to have all combat always be resolved via VATS? No, not really. Keep in mind that while VATS is active, your incoming damage is reduced by 90%, and your attacks have a 15% higher chance to be critical strikes. The downside to this is that your weapons will degrade at 400% of their normal rate in VATS. Don't think of VATS as a turn, but rather as a means of expending a resource (AP), to do more damage in less time while being somewhat more strategic.

Comment: I didn't know about VATS reducing incoming damage nor affecting critical chance. AWESOME! +1

Comment: Keep in mind that in New Vegas, the damage reduction has been cut form 90% to 25%, and the Crit bonus has been cut from 15% to 5% -  it's substantially less overpowered. Fortunately, the durability penalty was also removed.

Comment: I didn't know for the durability penalty. No wonder why I keep repairing stuff...