# VATS damage reduction in Fallout New Vegas

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

In Fallout 3, during VATS you had 90% damage reduction.

In Fallout New Vegas this seems to be considerably reduced. Is it known how big the damage reduction is now, or has it been removed entirely?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*Referring to the comments on the answer to [Make VATS the Default in Fallout 3?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10085/make-vats-the-default-in-fallout-3/10086#10086)*:
The damage reduction has apparently been reduced to **25%** in New Vegas (it was **90%** in fallout 3).

Additionally, the bonus to your chance to cause a critial strike has been reduced from 15% to 5%, and the increased wear on the used weapon has been removed entirely.

> Every melee weapon has a special attack, which can be selected using the triangle or Y buttons on the PS3 and Xbox 360, respectively.
>
> Unarmed weapons gain uppercut and cross at skill levels 50 and 75. These special attacks have an AP cost of 20 regardless of the weapon used.

Source: [V.A.T.S. article on the vault](http://www.falloutwiki.com/V.A.T.S#Fallout:_New_Vegas)

Comment: This Is Correct.